# select class b from mysql table of ips

Tags: mysql, select, ip

What is a method to extract the first two octets from a table of IPs (1.2.3.4) and put them into another table (1.2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

If IPs are stored as integers

```
SELECT ip, SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip, '.', 2) class
FROM
(
    SELECT INET_NTOA(167773449) ip
) t
```

Output

```
|       IP | CLASS |
--------------------
| 10.0.5.9 |  10.0 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/12899)**

If they are stored in a string representation then just

```
SELECT ip, SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip, '.', 2) class
  FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write an user defined function as below
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
and then run query
SELECT SPLIT_STR(ip, '.', 1) as first,
       SPLIT_STR(ip, '.', 2) as second
FROM   iptable;